# Airflow REST API Call From Within DAG?

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I'm running a local instance of [Airflow in Docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) (v2.6.1)

Calling the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/DAG) in a local file outside of Airflow to [create a connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_connection) works without issue:

```
import requests

def create_connection():
    response = requests.post(
        url='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/connections',
        headers={
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        auth=(
            'my_airflow_username',
            'my_airflow_password'
        ),
        json={
            'connection_id': 'new_connection',
            'conn_type': 'generic',
            'description': 'this is the description'
        }
    )
    return response

print(create_connection().status_code)
```

Returns status code `200` and creates the connection as expected.

But running the same code in a DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import requests

@dag(
    dag_id=f'test_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2023,5,11),
    schedule_interval=None,
    max_active_runs=1
)

def execute():

    def create_connection():
        response = requests.post(
            url='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/connections',
            headers={
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            auth=(
                'my_airflow_username',
                'my_airflow_password'
            ),
            json={
                'connection_id': 'new_connection',
                'conn_type': 'generic',
                'description': 'this is the description'
            }
        )
        return response

    create_connection = PythonOperator(
        task_id='create_connection',
        python_callable=create_connection
    )

    create_connection
    
execute()
```

errors and returns this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 710, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1281, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1327, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1276, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 205, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffff8bb14090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 788, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/connections (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffff8bb14090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 181, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 198, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/crmf/development/credential_testing/dag2.py", line 31, in create_connection
    'description': 'this is the description'
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/connections (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffff8bb14090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I expect to call the Airflow API from within my DAG just like any other API call. Any ideas on why the Airflow API connection fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the docker you are in the docker network and not in the host.

so the name of the webserver is "airflow-webserver" as you can see in the docker-compose services at same port 8080.

```
  airflow-webserver:
<<: *airflow-common
command: webserver
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
```

when you are calling from the dag its running on the airflow-worker container and "localhost" its the worker and not the webserver.

change "localhost" to "airflow-webserver"